# D3.js dynamic data/bandwidth labels for y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3.js line chart displaying bandwidth for a streaming service. I know of the .format method but it seems it only accepts Python formatting and has no built-in cleverness to deal with formatting of amounts of data.

All I have found when looking deeper into this are several people's ideas of how to improve Python's formatting tool:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578321-human-readable-filememory-sizes/
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/byteformat
etc.

However I would have no idea how to extend d3.js to include these extra options.

How can I get the scale and axis labels to cleverly switch between b/s, Kb/s and Mb/s etc?

A bonus would be to have a way to switch between bits and bytes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a formatter to translate the raw numbers to data size - see [PHP format bytes translation to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258025/php-format-bytes-translation-to-javascript) for one implementation.

Once you have such a formatter, you can pass it to the axis to use it in tick display, using `.tickFormat` ([docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat)):

```
myAxis.tickFormat(dataSizeFormatter);
```